# How do you I register for Electronic Data Interchange (EDI) ISA number?

Tags: edi

I will receive 850 purchase order. In return, I need to generate and send 997 response, which include ISA/GS number. Where and who do I register with for this ISA id?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDI systems are typically limited in scope to be between a few or even just 2 different organizations.  These organizations need to decide beforehand on how much of the full EDI specification they're going to use, and how they're going to specify IDs.  See [here](http://theintegrationengineer.com/usage-of-edi-specifications/).

Also, see [here](http://theintegrationengineer.com/edi-enveloping-part-two-the-isa/).  From this it looks like DUNS numbers or variants on them are common choices for IDs.

So your organization and the others need to just figure out if you're going to use DUNS number or ad-hoc made up numbers or what.

Comment: You don't have to register if both partners identify with ZZ. You can also use 12 for a telephone number, not much use without a modem

Answer (score 1):

Your 850 will have an ISA (interchange) and GS (group) identifier where you will be designated as the receiver.  When you generate the 997, the IDs will be reversed so that you are the sender of the acknowledgement.

Back in the day, it was important to uniquely identify yourself.  X12 handles this via a qualifier/ID pair.  Let's say you want to use your phone number.  Your ID would be 12 (qualifier) and then 5555551212 (your ID / phone number).  You could make up something arbitrary like ZZ (qualifier: mutally defined) and ACMEWIDGETSCO.  Again, it should be something unique and not already found on a VAN.  This is probably less probable these days than it was 10 years ago when everyone was using VANs predominantly.

Look at the below example.  The IDs in this example are made up, but could be DUNS, HIN, Industry identifier, phone number, mutually defined, etc.  Just for frame of reference, I used SENDER and RECEIVER.

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*SENDER          *ZZ*RECEIVER         *150622*2131*U*00401*000000006*0*T*>~
GS*PO*SENDER*RECEIVER*20150622*2131*4*X*004010~
```

In other words, you don't need to register it with anyone, you just need to make sure it is unique on the networks you are trading on with - that's really the important part.  If you're using direct connections (AS2, FTP) to your partners, it won't matter as much, but the best practice is to give your company an ID that is somewhat unique (DUNS, phone numbers, arbitrary name).  If you don't understand EDI, download EDI Notepad from Liaison and that should give you a better picture of how the data is described.